# Getting data from list

Tags: python, list

I am trying to fetch data from list

```
x = {'abc': 'value1', 'y': [{'key': '_Account_', 'value': 'my_account'}]}
```

using

```
list1.append([value.get('value') for value in list["x"]["y"]])
```

but the value is returned as `['my_account']` I need to get `my_account` not in the `['']`
Please tell me how can I get only string not in the square brackets with single quotes.

Comment: `x.get('y')[0].get('value')`

Answer (score 0):

```
x = {'abc': 'value1', 'y': [{'key': 'Account', 'value': 'my_account'}]}
data = x['y'][0]['value']
print(data)
```

will print: `my_account`